# Why do we choose |x+5|=10 in the following proof of quadratic limit?

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Prove: $$\lim_{x \to 5}x^2-x-6=14$$
Let $\epsilon>0$ be any number and we need to find some $\delta>0$ so that the following will be true.
$$|(x^2-x-6)-14| < \epsilon \ \ \ whenever \ \ \ 0<|x-5|<\delta \\|x^2-x-20|<\epsilon\\|x-5|.|x+4|<\epsilon\\|x-5|<\frac{\epsilon}{|x+4|}$$
Since the concept of limit only applies when $x$ is close to $a$, we will restrict $x$ so that it is at most $1$ away from $x$.
$$|x-5|<1\\ \Rightarrow-1<x-5<1\\ \Rightarrow8<x+4<10$$
Since $x+4>8>0$, $\ x+5=|x+5|\ $. So, $\ 8<|x+4|<10$.

*I understand everything up to this point. The following step is what I have a problem with.*

Now consider the original inequality $|x-5|<\frac{\epsilon}{|x+4|}$. Notice that the right hand side is at the minimum when $|x+4|$ is at its maximum. Since the maximum of $|x+4|$ is $10$, we know that
$$|x-5|<\frac{\epsilon}{|x+4|}<\frac{\epsilon}{10}$$

Since now we have two restrictions, $|x-5|<1$ and $|x-5|<\frac{\epsilon}{10}$ we let $\delta = min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{10})$.

---

Why do we choose the maximum value of $|x+4|$ which results in the minimum value of $\frac{\epsilon}{|x+4|}$?

Isn't $\frac{\epsilon}{|x+4|}<\frac{\epsilon}{10}$ a problem? Since $|x+4|$ is smaller than $10$ in which case $\frac{\epsilon}{|x+4|}$ is bigger than $\frac{\epsilon}{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $|x-5|<\frac{\epsilon}{|x+4|}<\frac{\epsilon}{10}$ is not correct. It should read $|x-5|<\frac{\epsilon}{10}<\frac{\epsilon}{|x+4|}$, since $|x+4|<10$. Furthermore I would write the proof in the following way:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Take $\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{10}\}$ then for all $x$ such that $|x-5|<\delta$ we have that
\begin{equation*}
|x-5|< 1 \Leftrightarrow -1<x-5<1 \Leftrightarrow 8<x+4<10.
\end{equation*}
Since $-10<x+4$ we have $|x+4|<10$. Furthermore by our definition of $\delta$ we have that $|x-5|<\frac{\epsilon}{10}$. Using these two inequalities we finally get:
\begin{equation*}
|(x^2-x-6)-14|=|x^2-x-20|=|x-5||x+4|<\frac{\epsilon}{10}\cdot 10=\epsilon.
\end{equation*}